# Why we use parameters in function when we can define variables in body of function?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

I am confuse at this point , We use parameter in python suppose this program:

## method 1

```
def f(x,y):
   z=x+y
   print(z)

f(1,2)
```

and if we don't pass parameter and do calculation like this :

## method 2

```
def f():
   x=1
   y=2
   z=x+y
   print(z)

f()
```

What is difference ,and Which one is good and why we pass parameter when we can use second method.

Comment: To pass parameters in from other function returns.

Comment: Because functions are there for reusability. You can't reuse a function, if it takes no parameters and is totally bound to its own local namespace. It's a math-inspired abstraction.

Comment: And how are you going to `print(z)` if print doesn't take any parameters, because it only prints the thing that was defined inside it?

Comment: Because for your second example, you can't do `f(3,4)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One simple way of looking at it is how it will affect the size of your codebase.  Consider needing to calculate f(1,2), f(3,4) and f(5,6) then you would need just one instance of your method 1 (called three times) or three instances of method 2 (also called three times).  So using method 1 saves the amount of code you need.

Comment: Thanks :) can you tell me what is exactly namespace is? why every tutorial saying its define in dict. what exactly it mean?

Answer (score 0):

One of the main point of passing parameters is that most of the time you don't know what they will be in advance so you can not hard-code them inside the function. Take the example: you wish to have a function that prints a greeting message to the user, clearly you don't know the name of all the future users of your program and you will only know the user's when he gives it to your program, so your only option is to give as parameter a variable containing that username you don't know yet:

```
def say_hello(username):
    print("Hello "+username+", nice to see you!")
```

An other point is that it allows your function to be reused with different parameters your `method2` will always give the same output *forever* while with `method1` you decide each time you call it what result you wish to see.

Comment: can't we do like 
def say_hello():
      user=input()
      print("Hello "+user+", nice to see you!")

Comment: Your function doesn't exactly behave like mine: in yours `user` is forgoten at the end of the function so you won't be able to say "hello" again or say "goodbye" without asking for the user to type his name again. While using a parameter here means that you can ask once for the user's name and say "hello" multiple times. That being said in many cases you could write a program defining only functions without arguments or even more extreme without defining any function at all but functions and arguments are there for your *convenience* at they will make your life *far* easier.